# XCode and new Qt version

Tags: ios, xcode, qt

I've an iOS application created with 5.7.1. The app needs some configuration that is done directly with XCode, so Qt Creator only was used for create the app the first time. From there, only XCode is used to compile and configure the app.

I've downloaded 5.7.2 because fix a bug, but, how can I change the XCode project to compile with the new Qt version?

Comment: Do you mean 5.6.2? Neither 5.7.1 nor 5.7.2 have been released so far.

Comment: Sorry, is from 5.7.0 to 5.7.1

Answer (score 0):

Open up your project in Xcode and:

1. First, open your target settings, and go to the **Build Phases** tab. Expand **Link Binary With Libraries**. Check if all QT frameworks you are using are set to link with the latest version.
2. Then, go to the **Build Settings** tab, and under **Search Paths** check whether the settings:

   - **Framework Search Paths**,
   - **Header Search Paths**,
   - and **Library Search Paths** contain the correct paths to the newer version of the QT build.
3. Last, on the same tab (**Build Settings**) under **Linking**, check if you have any QT-specific flags set for **Other Linker Flags** (e.g. -rpath, etc.)
4. Don't forget to check changelist in QT documentation for code changes, deprecations, etc. in the new QT version, and make the changes in your code accordingly.